# Black Bar at top of SplitViewcontrollers Navigationcontroller?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios7.1

This is only for landscape mode on the iPad because in portrait mode it was sorted by adding `popovercontroller.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1,0,0,0);`

There is a splitVC with a detailVC and navVC added which controls a rootVC.

This also does not happen in iOS 6 only iOS 7?

[image: Problem status bar?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the only thing that worked here was hiding the status bar all together. This was done in the plist file by adding :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you do not have a UINavigationController inside a UIViewController (besides the Split View controller)?

It also seems like you're using a custom background image. Make sure your background image is not 44pt tall (which is fine on iOS 6). On iOS 7, it should be 64pt (128px on a Retina) to correctly extend into the status bar area.

Comment: No it seems to have something to do with the frame settings?